# AWS VPN, and Lambda Javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, vpn

first of all I have 0 experience with javascript, but I need to create code for AWS VPN, to allow access only for certain public address. This is guide on the topic:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-admin/connection-authorization.html#connection-authorization-posture-assessment

It says "The Lambda function takes a JSON blob containing the following fields as input.".

How can I use a specific field(public-ip) to determine IP of the client?

So far my code looks like:

```
    exports.handler = async (event) => {
    
    
    
    const response = {
        
    "allow": true,
    "error-msg-on-failed-posture-compliance": "",
    "posture-compliance-statuses": [],
    "schema-version": "v1"
    
    }
    
    const response2 = {
        
    "allow": false,
    "error-msg-on-failed-posture-compliance": "",
    "posture-compliance-statuses": [],
    "schema-version": "v1"
    
    }
    
  return response;
 
};
```

both responses do their job, but now need a condition. I have no idea how to call that "BLOB".

Comment: Did you take a look what's inside `event`? My guess would be `event.public_ip`. Or take a look at the `arguments` to see what is passed to the lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Hi MyNicknameX for AWS you can grant access to people but no deny entry.

Let me know if this link works for you https://github.com/amliuyong/aws_learn/blob/ef973af6d370681b6f8a0149a59c902147335b07/AWS_Lambda_in_Action/README.md

Comment: What you mean, In above code, when "response" is returned vpn entry allowed, response2 - disallowed, tested and works.

Answer (score 0):

Got and answer on another forum. This is how you access: event["public-ip"]